# Connection: waitForSyncReply : Timed-out while waiting for reply in IONIC 3

Tags: ios, google-maps, ionic2, ionic3

I implemented Google Maps in IONIC 3.

On Android, it works fine. When I run it on IOS, it loads the map but when I perform any operation on it like zoom/drag, I'm getting a `Connection: waitForSyncReply: Timed-out while waiting for reply` error.

Comment: Hi, did you get solution to this problem ? I'm also facing the same problem so !

Comment: @Vasanth No luck yet.

Comment: I tried creating a new app and test the javascript google maps. There it works perfectly, but with my existing app, I'm facing this issue. If you come across solution anytime, then please do post here.

Comment: @Vasanth Sure. You too update if you got the solution

Comment: I tried lots of things, but nothing helped for me. Finally I created a new Ionic project and installed all the plugins of current project and copied the src. Though this is not the optimal solution, only this helped me.

Comment: Hi, @AkshayDeshmukh have you find out what caused this error?

Comment: Check out this link. [WebKit Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160240)